# Как управлять Qt GUI приложением из другого приложения?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, testng

Всем привет!
Возникла необходимость тестировать GUI Qt приложение методом фаззинга

Задача состоит в том, чтобы передавать в поля приложения данные

Каким образом можно запустить графическое приложение Qt и управлять его функционалом из другой C++ программы

`QTest` не подходит под мои задачи

я правильно понимаю что `QProcess` тоже не подходит, т.к. он только запускает процесс и может обмениваться данными с ним через стандартные потоки?

Comment: а почему QTest не подходит? Можно запустить поток и из него слать любые сообщения в GUI с помощью `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` в режиме `Qt::QueuedConnection`

Comment: @PavelGridin насколько я понял QTest компилируется в отдельный исполняемый файл, и тестирует отдельные функции какого либо класса
Мне же необходимо запускать GUI приложение и передавать через stdin данные в текстовые поля приложения( при этом нажимать кнопки "отправить" и т д

Comment: @PavelGridin, я имею ввиду что QTest не запускает полностью приложение тестируемое а лишь вызывает его отдельные функции ( я так понял)